# How to get confidence value in Face Detection using Haar Cascade

Tags: python, face-detection

I use open cv and haar cascade features to detect faces from an image. And after I load the cascade.xml library it will test the face read and draw a green rectangle in the face. My question is how to get confidence value from this library, like percentage or accusation value?

```
    import cv2 as cv
    
    img = cv.imread('Bryan/2.PNG')
    cv.imshow('Bryan', img)
    
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.imshow('Gray', gray)
    
    haar_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')
    
    faces_rect = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=6)
    
    print(f'Number of faces of found = {len(faces_rect)}')
    
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces_rect:
        cv.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
    
    cv.imshow('Detected faces', img)
    
    cv.waitKey(0)
```